# What does the Garmin GPSMAP 66 "SOS beacon" function do?

Tags: gps

According to the Garmin website, the [Garmin GPSmap 66](https://www.garmin.com/en-GB/blog/garmin-refreshes-its-popular-handheld-gpsmap-series-introduces-larger-display-galileo-support-and-expanded-battery-life-with-tracking-up-to-one-week/) includes an *SOS beacon*:

> These devices include an LED flashlight and SOS beacon that can be used to signal for help.

They are thin on details, and Google Search just turns up the exact same formulation on different websites.  What does this SOS beacon actually do?  Is it anything like a PLB, is it an audible/visible alarm, or something different from either?

Comment: Since it has an LED flashlight, I guess the SOS beacon is the LED flashing SOS in Morse Code (3 short flashes, 3 long and 3 short again).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [pictures](https://buy.garmin.com/en-GB/GB/p/598455#overview) and how it is talked about, it's **probably just a strobe mode** for the flashlight.

[image]

> The built-in **LED flashlight/SOS Beacon** is a great backup if needed in an emergency for added piece of mind when you’re away from civilization.

[Source](https://www.thegpsstore.com/Garmin-GPSMAP-66s-Handheld-GPS-P5696.aspx)